# read 2d List as space separated values in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I want to read 2d list from the user as space separated values like this format :

```
0 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 1  
0 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 0
```

and here is my code :

```
# Read Matrix of 5X5
mat = [[int(input()) for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: Try `mat = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for x in range(5)]`

Comment: @Vishal I want the input to be read as 5 space separated values then go to newline and read another 5 and so on , not to read one value at one line

Comment: @iz_ This exactly what i need thank u very much ^^

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```
mat = [list(map(int, input().split())) for y in range(5)]
```

This will take 5 lists line by line to create the matrix.